# EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code = 1, address= 0x16)

Tags: c++, xcode, exception

I can't resolve this problem and I'm trying to resolve it in each way
the line which get this error is:

```
void Encoder::generateCodes(const Node &node, const std::vector<bool>& prefix)
{
    if (&node.left() == &HT::NIL and &node.right() == &HT::NIL)//if is a leaf
    {
```

---

```
      *codes[static_cast<unsigned long>(node.key())] = prefix;
```

---

```
    }
    else
    {
        std::vector<bool> leftPrefix = prefix;
        leftPrefix.push_back(false);
        generateCodes(node.left(), leftPrefix);

        std::vector<bool> rightPrefix = prefix;
        rightPrefix.push_back(true);
        generateCodes(node.right(), rightPrefix);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to implement a Huffman encoding and this function takes the Huffman tree as argument and for each character gives his binary code.
From what I understand the error is thrown when the compiler tries to resize the vector  to insert a new element bool.
In fact, if I look at calls on the stack, the exact line that causes the exception is this:

```
    if (__v.__size_ > capacity())
```

Comment: is a sentinel Node
`static Node<Key,Data> NIL;`
a static member of
`template <class Key,class Data>class BST`

Comment: try to post a complete but reduced-to-minimal example that readers can try

Comment: I had a dynamic attribute and I hadn't allocate memory for this ,Xcode don't noticed me.